# Can modern x86 hardware not store a single byte to memory?

Tags: c++, assembly, concurrency, x86, memory-model

Speaking of the memory model of C++ for concurrency, Stroustrup's *C++ Programming Language,* 4th ed., sect. 41.2.1, says:

> ... (like most modern hardware) the machine could not load or store anything smaller than a word.

However, my x86 processor, a few years old, can and does store objects smaller than a word.  For example:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    char a =  5;
    char b = 25;
    a = b;
    std::cout << int(a) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Without optimization, GCC compiles this as:

```
        [...]
        movb    $5, -1(%rbp)   # a =  5, one byte
        movb    $25, -2(%rbp)  # b = 25, one byte
        movzbl  -2(%rbp), %eax # load b, one byte, not extending the sign
        movb    %al, -1(%rbp)  # a =  b, one byte
        [...]
```

The comments are by me but the assembly is by GCC. It runs fine, of course.

Obviously, I do not understand what Stroustrup is talking about when he explains that hardware can load and store nothing smaller than a word. As far as I can tell, my program does nothing *but* load and store objects smaller than a word.

The thoroughgoing focus of C++ on zero-cost, hardware-friendly abstractions sets C++ apart from other programming languages that are easier to master. Therefore, if Stroustrup has an interesting mental model of signals on a bus, or has something else of this kind, then I would like to understand Stroustrup's model.

What *is* Stroustrup talking about, please?

**LONGER QUOTE WITH CONTEXT**

Here is Stroustrup's quote in fuller context:

> Consider what might happen if a linker allocated [variables of `char` type like] `c` and `b` in the same word in memory and (like most modern hardware) the machine could not load or store anything smaller than a word.... Without a well-defined and reasonable memory model, thread 1 might read the word containing `b` and `c`, change `c`, and write the word back into memory. At the same time, thread 2 could do the same with `b`. Then, whichever thread managed to read the word first and whichever thread managed to write its result back into memory last would determine the result....

**ADDITIONAL REMARKS**

I do not believe that Stroustrup is talking about cache lines. Even if he were, as far as I know, cache coherency protocols would transparently handle that problem except maybe during hardware I/O.

I have checked my processor's hardware datasheet. Electrically, my processor (an Intel Ivy Bridge) seems to address DDR3L memory by some sort of 16-bit multiplexing scheme, so I don't know what that's about. It is not clear to me that that has much to do with Stroustrup's point, though.

Stroustrup is a smart man and an eminent scientist, so I do not doubt that he is taking about something sensible. I am confused.

See also [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19903338/1275653) My question resembles the linked question in several ways, and the answers to the linked question are also helpful here. However, my question goes also to the hardware/bus model that motivates C++ to be the way it is and that causes Stroustrup to write what he writes. I do not seek an answer merely regarding that which the C++ standard formally guarantees, but also wish to understand why the C++ standard would guarantee it. What is the underlying thought? This is part of my question, too.

Comment: The CPU certainly has instructions for fiddling individual bytes. But RAM is stored in discrete words; depending on what particular family the x86 CPU belongs to, two, four, or maybe eight bytes. I don't recall at the top off my head, you're pretty much insulated from these things, when hacking C++. So, when the CPU needs to fiddle a single byte it fetches the entire word from RAM, messes with a single byte, then sends it back where it came from. That's, basically, the capsule summary of the general process, but, of course, there's much more complexity in actuality.

Comment: @old_timer: Interesting. I had thought that the [MESI protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10058243/1275653) solved this issue (except maybe for a performance hit due to an otherwise unnecessary cache-line writeback/invalidation), but I don't know enough about it to be sure.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: That's a useful comment. I have read things a little like that before, so it sounds right, at least. However, isn't my code literally a counterexample?

Comment: depends on the definition of "cpu" the processor core may send a byte write out, that core doesnt do the read-modify-write that happens down the line, and in an x86 system there are a lot of layers and a lot of busses, ideally only one layer has to deal with it and the remaining layers get full width transactions and read-modify-writes are not a problem.  The hardware takes care of this is the short answer, maybe back on the 8088/8086 this was something to worry about, but if you are seeing these kinds of problems on anything recent, buy a new computer.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: That's not correct.  Modern CPUs will fetch whole cache lines (typically 64 bytes) and track dirty / not-dirty on a per-cache-line basis.  So two adjacent bytes is pretty much exactly the same as two adjacent words, if they're both in the same cache line.  Writing one will result in a fetch of the whole line, and eventually a write-back of the whole line.  Only a very few CPUs don't have byte-load and byte-store instructions (early Alpha AXP is one classic example: processing chars in a string involved word-loads and shift/mask).  working on writing this as an answer.

Comment: the cache is built out of smaller memories, not necessarily the whole width of the cache line, it is implementation/foundry dependent, even when changing the same higher level design to a new process, that means new cell library, which means new widths. the opportunity to not do a full cache line width read-modify-write becomes possible but up to the designer, as with software they can abstract it at whatever level they want…can be full width too, depends on the cell library. granted intel both does the chip designs and makes or has the cell library made so they can influence what is available

Comment: would require more logic to take advantage of partial line modifications, you could do for example two or more modifications to the line at a time, but would have to have more logic for that, so full line modification does make the most sense and requires the least work from the logic designer/design.

Comment: @old_timer: Is it common to track dirty/clean on a smaller granularity than a full cache line?  That is different from just using smaller cache lines, but does add to the complexity of state management.  I'd guess that you'd probably consider the whole line dirty for MESI, but maybe optimize write-back to DRAM if you're using DRAM that supports smaller burst sizes.  (DDR1/2/3/4's SDRAM natural burst size is up to 64B, IIRC.  See [What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf))

Comment: clean/dirty only makes sense on a whole line, the definition of a cache line is implementation defined, x86 vs arm vs other, this x86 chip vs that, this motherboard design vs that, etc...

Comment: I read this question as Stroustrup is trying to convey that memory is not 8 bits wide (although it often is but is not treated that way), particularly the memory in the caches along the way to the dram.  Those can be anywhere from the width of the line to fractions of, but most folks even some of the chip designers dont need to know or care.  You want to write 8 bits into a line you worst case have to do a read-modify-write of the whole line, but that is atomic in a sane design, as the round trip is like two or so clocks, the "cpu" as in the processor core doesnt do this thats crazy.

Comment: DDR1/2/3/4 is actually implemented in 8 or 16 or 32 bit wide parts, that si why your memory stick has 8 parts on one side or both or 4 parts on one side or both (or perhaps even 2 on one side or both this far down the DDR3 path).  But the memory controllers do not access them like that (in an x86 pc design), but the same memory controller IP might very well be able to access them as 32 bits wide for say a different platform, a phone for example.  Depends on the ip you buy and what you are doing with it.

Comment: If you want to confirm for yourself that you can write a byte, use whatever software magic (or assembly) you choose to write a word/dword to some address then write a byte to one of those bytes you just wrote read the word back, note that your byte write worked...if you think there is optimization magic, then have the program wait a few hours between each write and the read, do other stuff lots of programs switching in and out...see that the byte changed...

Comment: You also dont get an "at the same time", even if dual/multi ported...the transactions at some layer become serialized one then the other.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19903338/c-memory-model-and-race-conditions-on-char-arrays

Comment: @thb: I think this question is a possible duplicate of the one you linked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19903338/c-memory-model-and-race-conditions-on-char-arrays.  The answers there point out that C++11 currently *requires* the ability to modify a `char` without non-atomic RMW of surrounding data.  (So `char` must be word-sized on machines that can't atomically store just a byte, and most C++ implementations for modern CPUs other than DSPs have 8-bit `char`).  **Stroustrup is just totally wrong on this** (esp. in 2017). Anyway, if you'd rather not close as duplicate, maybe alter the Q?

Comment: @PeterCordes - are we sure we are interpreting the question properly? I take Stroustrup's quote to address memory alignment rather than what a CPU can do. Of course a CPU can twiddle bits and bytes, but that doesn't change the memory alignment requirement. I may be interpreting what he is saying wrong, but I see the discussion somewhat mixing apples and oranges.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: The context is what happens if the linker places `char b,c;` in the same word.  They're both single bytes, and nobody's talking about getting them both with an unaligned load.  (The OP quoted the full paragraph later.)

Comment: I'll defer to your collective wisdom, I just wanted to insure nothing was slipping though the cracks.

Comment: @PeterCordes: You are right. I cannot wholly separate my question from the earlier question except insofar as that my question is more precisely posed. However, there are some other, minor differences. To the best of my imperfect ability, I have edited the question to accentuate the differences, such as they are.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: I think you had a good point after all.  Maybe Stroustrup wasn't really talking about externally-visible CPU behaviour, just what they might do internally.  I finally finished [writing up an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46721075/can-modern-x86-hardware-not-store-a-single-byte-to-memory/46818162#46818162) after several rewrites.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**TL:DR: On every modern ISA that has byte-store instructions (including x86), they're atomic and don't disturb surrounding bytes.**  (I'm not aware of any older ISAs where byte-store instructions could "invent writes" to neighbouring bytes either.)

The actual implementation mechanism ([in non-x86 CPUs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54217528/are-there-any-modern-cpus-where-a-cached-byte-store-is-actually-slower-than-a-wo)) is sometimes an internal RMW cycle to modify a whole word in a cache line, but that's done "invisibly" inside a core while it has exclusive ownership of the cache line so it's only ever a performance problem, not correctness.  (And merging in the store buffer can sometimes turn byte-store instructions into an efficient full-word commit to L1d cache.)

---

---

#### About Stroustrup's phrasing

I don't think it's a very accurate, clear or useful statement.  It would be more accurate to say that modern CPUs can't load or store anything smaller than a cache line.  (Although that's not true for uncacheable memory regions, e.g. for MMIO.)

**It probably would have been better just to make a hypothetical example to talk about memory models**, rather than implying that real hardware is like this.  But if we try, we can maybe find an interpretation that isn't as obviously or totally wrong, which might have been what Stroustrup was thinking when he wrote this to introduce the topic of memory models.  (Sorry this answer is so long; I ended up writing a lot while guessing what he might have meant and about related topics...)

Or maybe this is another case of high-level language designers not being hardware experts, or at least occasionally making mis-statements.

---

I think Stroustrup is talking about how CPUs work *internally* to implement byte-store instructions.  He's suggesting that a CPU *without a well-defined and reasonable memory model* might implement a byte-store with a non-atomic RMW of the containing word in a cache line, or in memory for a CPU without cache.

**Even this weaker claim about internal (not externally visible) behaviour is not true for high-performance x86 CPUs**.  Modern Intel CPUs have no throughput penalty for byte stores, or even unaligned word or vector stores that don't cross a cache-line boundary.  AMD is similar.

If byte or unaligned stores had to do a RMW cycle as the store committed to L1D cache, it would interfere with store and/or load instruction/uop throughput in a way we could measure with performance counters.  (In a carefully designed experiment that avoids the possibility of store coalescing in the store buffer before commit to L1d cache hiding the cost, because the store execution unit(s) can only run 1 store per clock on current CPUs.)

---

However, **some high performance designs for non-x86 ISAs do use an atomic RMW cycle to internally commit stores to L1d cache.  [Are there any modern CPUs where a cached byte store is actually slower than a word store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54217528/are-there-any-modern-cpus-where-a-cached-byte-store-is-actually-slower-than-a-wo)**  The cache line stays in MESI Exclusive/Modified state the whole time, so it can't introduce any correctness problems, only a small performance hit.  This is very different from doing something that could step on stores from other CPUs.  (The arguments below about *that* not happening still apply, but my update may have missed some stuff that still argues that atomic cache-RMW is unlikely.)

(On many non-x86 ISAs, unaligned stores are not supported at all, or are used more rarely than in x86 software.  And weakly-ordered ISAs allow more coalescing in store buffers, so not as many byte store instructions actually result in single-byte commit to L1d.  Without these motivations for fancy (power hungry) cache-access hardware, word RMW for scattered byte stores is an acceptable tradeoff in some designs.)

---

**Alpha AXP**, a high-performance RISC design from 1992, famously (and uniquely among modern non-DSP ISAs) **omitted byte load/store instructions until** [Alpha 21164A (EV56) in 1996](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_21164#Description_2).  Apparently they didn't consider word-RMW a viable option for implementing byte stores, because one of the cited advantages for implementing only 32-bit and 64-bit aligned stores was more efficient ECC for the L1D cache.  ["Traditional SECDED ECC would require 7 extra bits over 32-bit granules (22% overhead) versus 4 extra bits over 8-bit granules (50% overhead)."](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/42765/advantage-of-byte-addressable-memory-over-word-addressable-memory)    (@Paul A. Clayton's answer about word vs. byte addressing has some other interesting computer-architecture stuff.)  If byte stores were implemented with word-RMW, you could still do error detection/correction with word-granularity.

Current Intel CPUs only use parity (not ECC) in L1D for this reason. (At least some older Xeons could run with L1d in ECC mode at half capacity instead of the normal 32KiB, as [discussed on RWT](https://www.realworldtech.com/forum/?threadid=161949&curpostid=161949).  It's not clear if anything's changed, e.g. in terms of Intel now using ECC for L1d). See also [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47417481/what-specifically-marks-an-x86-cache-line-as-dirty-any-write-or-is-an-explici) about hardware (not) eliminating "silent stores": checking the old contents of cache before the write to avoid marking the line dirty if it matched would require a RMW instead of just a store, and that's a major obstacle.

It turns out some high-perf pipelined designs do use atomic word-RMW to commit to L1d, despite it stalling the memory pipeline, but (as I argue below) it's *much* less likely that any do an externally-visible RMW to RAM.

Word-RMW isn't a useful option for [MMIO](http://I%20assume%20that%20most%20other%20modern%20CPU%20designs%20are%20like%20this,%20too.%20%20Word-RMW%20isn%27t%20a%20useful%20option%20for%20MMIO%20byte%20stores,%20so%20unless%20you%20have%20an%20architecture%20that%20doesn%27t%20need%20sub-word%20stores%20for%20IO,%20you%27d%20need%20some%20kind%20of%20special%20handling%20for%20IO%20or%20.%20%20%20Maybe%20some%20low-power%20single-core%20CPUs%20do%20actual%20RMW%20for%20byte%20stores;%20on%20a%20single-core) byte stores either, so unless you have an architecture that doesn't need sub-word stores for IO, you'd need some kind of special handling for IO (like [Alpha's sparse I/O space](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Alpha-HOWTO-8.html) where word load/stores were mapped to byte load/stores so it could use commodity PCI cards instead of needing special hardware with no byte IO registers).

As [@Margaret points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46721075/can-modern-x86-hardware-not-store-a-single-byte-to-memory/46733018#46733018), DDR3 memory controllers can do byte stores by setting control signals that mask out other bytes of a burst.  The same mechanisms that get this information to the memory controller (for uncached stores) could also get that information passed along with a load or store to MMIO space.  So there are hardware mechanisms for really doing
a byte store even on burst-oriented memory systems, and it's highly likely that modern CPUs will use that instead of implementing an RMW, because it's probably simpler and is *much* better for MMIO correctness.

**[How many and what size cycles will be needed to perform longword transferred to the CPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49882244/how-many-and-what-size-cycles-will-be-needed-to-perform-longword-transferred-to) shows how a ColdFire microcontroller signals the transfer size (byte/word/longword/16-byte line) with external signal lines,** letting it do byte loads/stores even if 32-bit-wide memory was hooked up to its 32-bit data bus.  Something like this is presumably typical for most memory bus setups (but I don't know).  The ColdFire example is complicated by also being configurable to use 16 or 8-bit memory, taking extra cycles for wider transfers.  But nevermind that, the important point is that it has *external* signaling for the transfer size, to tell the memory HW which byte it's actually writing.

---

**Stroustrup's [next paragraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46721075/can-modern-x86-hardware-not-store-a-single-byte-to-memory/46722569?noredirect=1#comment80393577_46722569) is**

> "The C++ memory model guarantees that [two threads of execution can update and access separate memory locations without interfering with each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19903338/c-memory-model-and-race-conditions-on-char-arrays/19903377#19903377). This is exactly what we would naively expect. It is the compiler’s job to protect us from the sometimes very strange and subtle behaviors of modern hardware. How a compiler and hardware combination achieves that is up to the compiler. ..."

So apparently he thinks that real modern hardware may not provide "safe" byte load/store.  The people who design hardware memory models agree with the C/C++ people, and realize that byte store instructions would not be very useful to programmers / compilers if they could step on neighbouring bytes.

**All modern (non-DSP) architectures except early Alpha AXP have byte store and load  instructions, and AFAIK these are all architecturally defined to not affect neighbouring bytes.**  However they accomplish that in hardware, software doesn't need to care about correctness.  Even the very first version of MIPS (in 1983) had byte and half-word loads/stores, and it's a very word-oriented ISA.

However, he doesn't actually claim that most modern hardware needs any special compiler support to implement this part of the C++ memory model, just that *some* might.  Maybe he really is only talking about word-addressable DSPs in that 2nd paragraph (where C and C++ implementations often use 16 or 32-bit `char` as exactly the kind of compiler workaround Stroustrup was talking about.)

---

**Most "modern" CPUs (including all x86) have an L1D cache**.  They will fetch whole cache lines (typically 64 bytes) and track dirty / not-dirty on a per-cache-line basis.  **So two adjacent bytes are pretty much exactly the same as two adjacent words, if they're both in the same cache line.**  Writing one byte or word will result in a fetch of the whole line, and eventually a write-back of the whole line.  See Ulrich Drepper's [What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf).  You're correct that [MESI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol) (or a derivative like MESIF/MOESI) makes sure this isn't a problem.  (But again, this is because hardware implements a sane memory model.)

A store can only commit to L1D cache while the line is in the Modified state (of MESI).  So even if the internal hardware implementation is slow for bytes and takes extra time to merge the byte into the containing word in the cache line, it's effectively an *atomic* read modify write as long as it doesn't allow the line to be invalidated and re-acquired between the read and the write. ([While this cache has the line in Modified state, no other cache can have a valid copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39393850/can-num-be-atomic-for-int-num)).  See [@old_timer's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46721075/can-modern-x86-hardware-not-store-a-single-byte-to-memory#comment80389962_46721075) making the same point (but also for RMW in a memory controller).

This is easier than e.g. an atomic `xchg` or `add` from a register that also needs an ALU and register access, since all the HW involved is in the same pipeline stage, which can simply stall for an extra cycle or two.  That's obviously bad for performance and takes extra hardware to allow that pipeline stage to signal that it's stalling.  This doesn't necessarily conflict with Stroustrup's first claim, because he was talking about a hypothetical ISA without a memory model, but it's still a stretch.

On a single-core microcontroller, internal word-RMW for cached byte stores would be more plausible, since there won't be Invalidate requests coming in from other cores that they'd have to delay responding to during an atomic RMW cache-word update.  But that doesn't help for I/O to uncacheable regions.  I say microcontroller because other single-core CPU designs typically support some kind of multi-socket SMP.

---

Many RISC ISAs don't support unaligned-word loads/stores with a single instruction, but that's a separate issue (the difficulty is handling the case when a load spans two cache lines or even pages, which can't happen with bytes or aligned half-words).  More and more ISAs are adding guaranteed support for unaligned load/store in recent versions, though.  (e.g. [MIPS32/64 Release 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture#MIPS32.2FMIPS64_Release_6) in 2014, and I think AArch64 and recent 32-bit ARM.  Also RISC-V, but it allows that to be implemented with a trap to a misalignment handler).

---

[The 4th edition](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html) of Stroustrup's book was published in 2013 when Alpha had been dead for years.  The first edition was [published in 1985](http://www.stroustrup.com/1st.html), when RISC was the new big idea (e.g. Stanford MIPS in 1983, [according to Wikipedia's timeline of computing HW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_computing_hardware_(1960s%E2%80%93present)), but "modern" CPUs at that time were byte-addressable with byte stores.  Cyber CDC 6600 was word-addressable and probably still around, but couldn't be called modern.

Even very word-oriented RISC machines like [MIPS](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html) and [SPARC](http://moss.csc.ncsu.edu/%7Emueller/codeopt/codeopt00/notes/sparc.html) have byte store and byte load (with sign or zero extension) instructions.  They don't support unaligned word loads, simplifying the cache (or memory access if there is no cache) and load ports, but you can load any single byte with one instruction, and more importantly *store* a byte without any architecturally-visible non-atomic rewrite of the surrounding bytes.  (Cached stores can coalesce in the store buffer to potentially complete a full write of an 4-byte or 8-byte chunk, avoiding the need for special handling of that commit in that case.)

I suppose C++11 (which introduces a thread-aware memory model to the language) on Alpha would need to use 32-bit `char` if targeting a version of the Alpha ISA without byte stores.  Or it would have to use software atomic-RMW with LL/SC when it couldn't prove that no other threads could have a pointer that would let them write neighbouring bytes.

---

**IDK *how* slow byte load/store instructions are in any CPUs where they're implemented in hardware but not as cheap as word loads/stores**.  Byte loads are cheap on x86 as long as you use `movzx/movsx` to avoid partial-register false dependencies or merging stalls.  [On AMD pre-Ryzen, `movsx`/`movzx` needs an extra ALU uop, but otherwise zero/sign extension is handled right in the load port on Intel and AMD CPUs.](http://agner.org/optimize/))  The main x86 downside is that you need a separate load instruction instead of using a memory operand as a source for an ALU instruction (if you're adding a zero-extended byte to a 32-bit integer), saving front-end uop throughput bandwidth and code-size.  Or if you're just adding a byte to a byte register, there's basically no downside on x86.  RISC load-store ISAs always need separate load and store instructions anyway.  x86 byte stores are no more expensive that 32-bit stores.

As a performance issue, a good C++ implementation for hardware with slow byte stores might put each `char` in its own word and use word loads/stores whenever possible (e.g. for globals outside structs, and for locals on the stack).  IDK if any real implementations of MIPS / ARM / whatever have slow byte load/store, but if so maybe gcc has `-mtune=` options to control it.

[That doesn't help for `char[]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19903338/c-memory-model-and-race-conditions-on-char-arrays/19903377#19903377), or dereferencing a `char *` when you don't know where it might be pointing.  (This includes `volatile char*` which you'd use for MMIO.)  So having the compiler+linker put `char` variables in separate words isn't a complete solution, just a performance hack if true byte stores are slow.

---

**PS: More about Alpha:**

Alpha is interesting for a lot of reasons: one of the few clean-slate 64-bit ISAs, not an extension to an existing 32-bit ISA.  And one of the more recent clean-slate ISAs, Itanium being another from several years later which attempted some neat CPU-architecture ideas.

> From [the Linux Alpha HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Alpha-HOWTO-8.html).

> When the Alpha architecture was introduced, **it was unique** amongst RISC architectures for eschewing 8-bit and 16-bit loads and stores. It supported 32-bit and 64-bit loads and stores (longword and quadword, in Digital's nomenclature). The co-architects (Dick Sites, Rich Witek) justified this decision by citing the advantages:

> 1. Byte support in the cache and memory sub-system tends to slow down accesses for 32-bit and 64-bit quantities.
> 2. Byte support makes it hard to build high-speed error-correction circuitry into the cache/memory sub-system.

> Alpha compensates by providing powerful instructions for manipulating bytes and byte groups within 64-bit registers. Standard benchmarks for string operations (e.g., some of the Byte benchmarks) show that Alpha performs very well on byte manipulation.

Comment: I don't know what you do for your day job, but I understand and recognize the depth of knowledge required to collect in your mind that level of detail covering the RMW cycle and CPU/cache behavior for a span of two decades, and more, of hardware development at the byte/word+ load level. I always learn how much I have yet to learn from your answers `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: I do freelance optimization / tuning stuff when I'm not contributing to free software or improving the state of knowledge here on SO.  And thanks, I just hope I'm right about the parts I guessed about (e.g. that very few microarchitectures do actually use an internal RMW for byte stores.)  I don't really have practical experience with much outside of recent x86, but I've been interested in reading about CPU design for a long time.

Comment: Also wrt. write inventions, see [Herb Sutter's atomic<> Weapons part 2 @3:14](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-atomic-Weapons-2-of-2/player#time=3m14s)

Comment: ^^ although it should be noted that internal (atomic) word-RMW for byte stores _are_ allowed by ISO C++ since they're not _externally_ visible.

Answer (score 9):

Not only are x86 CPUs capable of reading and writing a single byte, all modern general purpose CPUs are capable of it.  More importantly most modern CPUs (including x86, ARM, MIPS, PowerPC, and SPARC) are capable of atomically reading and writing single bytes.

I'm not sure what Stroustrup was referring to.  There used to be a few word addressable machines that weren't capable of 8-bit byte addressing, like the Cray, and as Peter Cordes mentioned early Alpha CPUs didn't support byte loads and stores, but today the only CPUs incapable of byte loads and stores are certain DSPs used in niche applications. Even if we assume he means most modern CPUs don't have atomic byte load and stores this isn't true of most CPUs.

However, simple atomic loads and stores aren't of much use in multithreaded programming. You also typically need ordering guarantees and a way to make read-modify-write operations atomic. Another consideration is that while CPU a may have byte load and store instructions, compiler isn't required to use them. A compiler, for example, could still generate the code Stroustrup describes, loading both `b` and `c` using a single word load instruction as an optimization.

So while you do need a well defined memory model, if only so the compiler is forced to generate the code you expect, the problem isn't that modern CPUs aren't capable of loading or storing anything smaller than a word.

Comment: I dont see the quote saying reading the word in a single load as an optimization to get b and c in one instruction.   It is not uncommon (in general not necessarily x86 specific) that on a read the bus width is read, and in the cpu the byte lane in question is isolated as you get closer to the processor core.  I think the quote is assuming that the processor reads the whole word modifies one byte and writes it back and if you have thread 1's read start, then thread 2's read start, then thread one writes then thread two writes, thread 1's byte is lost. but thats not how it works.

Comment: old ARM CPUs also don't have instructions to load/store halfwords

Comment: the problem doesnt require a 16 bit location two 8 bit bytes in a 32 bit location will work as well.  the arm1 looks like a 32 bit data bus so it would/could have the issue if there were an issue here.  (and a "word" in arm is 32 bits).  If I am reading this right the armv3 didnt have strh either, but we know that armv4 does of course.

Comment: I used to write for a Texas TMS9995 processor in C. That processor could only load/store 16-bit words. byte operations had to be done as a read-modify-write IIRC.

Answer (score 2):

The author seems to be concerned about thread 1 and thread 2 getting into a situation where the read-modify-writes (not in software, the software does two separate instructions of a byte size, somewhere down the line logic has to do a read-modify-write) instead of the ideal read modify write read modify write, becomes a read read modify modify write write or some other timing such that both read the pre-modified version and the last one to write wins.  read read modify modify write write, or read modify read modify write write or read modify read write modify write.

The concern is to start with 0x1122 and one thread wants to make it 0x33XX the other wants to make it 0xXX44, but with for example a read read modify modify write write you end up with 0x1144 or 0x3322, but not 0x3344

A sane (system/logic) design just doesn't have that problem certainly not for a general purpose processor like this, I have worked on designs with timing issues like this but that is not what we are talking about here, completely different system designs for different purposes.  The read-modify-write does not span a long enough distance in a sane design, and x86s are sane designs.

The read-modify-write would happen very near the first SRAM involved (ideally L1 when running an x86 in a typical fashion with an operating system capable of running C++ compiled multi-threaded programs) and happen within a few clock cycles as the ram is at the speed of the bus ideally.  And as Peter pointed out this is considered to be the whole cache line that experiences this, within the cache, not a read-modify-write between the processor core and the cache.

The notion of "at the same time" even with multi-core systems isn't necessarily at the same time, eventually you get serialized because performance isn't based on them being parallel from beginning to end, it is based on keeping the busses loaded.

The quote is saying variables allocated to the same word in memory, so that is the same program.  Two separate programs are not going to share an address space like that. so

You are welcome to try this, make a multithreaded program that one writes to say address 0xnnn00000 the other writes to address 0xnnnn00001, each does a write, then a read or better several writes of the same value than one read, check the read was the byte they wrote, then repeats with a different value.  Let that run for a while, hours/days/weeks/months.  See if you trip up the system...use assembly for the actual write instructions to make sure it is doing what you asked (not C++ or any compiler that does or claims it will not put these items in the same word).  Can add delays to allow for more cache evictions, but that reduces your odds of "at the same time" collisions.

Your example so long as you insure you are not sitting on two sides of a boundary (cache, or other) like 0xNNNNFFFFF and 0xNNNN00000, isolate the two byte writes to addresses like 0xNNNN00000 and 0xNNNN00001 have the instructions back to back and see if you get a read read modify modify write write.  Wrap a test around it, that the two values are different each loop, you read back the word as a whole at whatever delay later as you desire and check the two values.  Repeat for days/weeks/months/years to see if it fails.  Read up on your processors execution and microcode features to see what it does with this instruction sequence and as needed create a different instruction sequence that tries to get the transactions initiated within a handful or so clock cycles on the far side of the processor core.

EDIT

the problem with the quotes is that this is all about language and the use of.  "like most modern hardware" puts the whole of the topic/text in a touchy position, it is too vague, one side can argue all I have to do is find one case that is true to make all the rest true, likewise one side could argue if I find one case the all of the rest is not true.  Using the word like kind of messes with that as a possible get out of jail free card.

The reality is that a significant percentage of our data is stored in DRAM in 8 bit wide memories, just that we don't access them as 8 bit wide normally we access 8 of them at a time, 64 bits wide.  In some number of weeks/months/years/decades this statement will be incorrect.

The larger quote says "at the same time" and then says read ... first,  write ... last, well first and last and at the same time don't make sense together, is it parallel or serial?  The context as a whole is concerned about the above read read modify modify write write variations where you have one writing last and depending on when that one read determines if both modifications happened or not.  Not about at the same time which "like most modern hardware" doesn't make sense things that start off actually parallel in separate cores/modules eventually get serialized if they are aiming at the same flip-flop/transistor in a memory, one eventually has to wait for the other to go first.  Being physics based I don't see this being incorrect in the coming weeks/months/years.

Answer (score 2):

This is correct. An x86_64 CPU, just like an original x86 CPU, is not able to read or write anything smaller than an (in this case 64-bit) word from rsp. to memory. And it will not typically read or write less than a whole cache line, though there are ways to bypass the cache, especially in writing (see below).

*In this context*, though, Stroustrup refers to potential data races (lack of atomicity on an observable level). This correctness issue is irrelevant on x86_64, because of the cache coherency protocol, which you mentioned. In other words, yes, the CPU is limited to whole word transfers, *but* this is transparently handled, and you as a programmer generally do not have to worry about it. In fact, the C++ language, starting from C++11, *guarantees* that concurrent operations on distinct memory locations have well-defined behavior, i.e. the one you'd expect. Even if the hardware did not guarantee this, the implementation would have to find a way by generating possibly more complex code.

That said, it can still be a good idea to keep the fact that whole words or even cache lines are always involved at the machine level in the back of your head, for two reasons.

- First, and this is only relevant for people who write device drivers, or design devices, memory-mapped I/O may be sensitive to the way it is accessed. As an example, think of a device that exposes a 64-bit write-only command register in the physical address space. It may then be necessary to:

  - Disable caching. It is not valid to read a cache line, change a single word, and write back the cache line. Also, even if it were valid, there would still be a great risk that commands might be lost because the CPU cache is not written back soon enough. At the very least, the page needs to be configured as "write-through", which means writes take immediate effect. Therefore, an x86_64 page table entry contains flags that control the CPU's caching behavior *for this page*.
  - Ensure that the whole word is always written, on the assembly level. E.g. consider a case where you write the value 1 into the register, followed by a 2. A compiler, especially when optimizing for space, might decide to overwrite only the least significant byte because the others are already supposed to be zero (that is, for ordinary RAM), or it might instead remove the first write because this value appears to be immediately overwritten anyway. However, neither is supposed to happen here. In C/C++, the `volatile` keyword is vital to prevent such unsuitable optimizations.
- Second, and this is relevant for almost any developer writing multi-threaded programs, the cache coherency protocol, while neatly averting disaster, can have a huge performance cost if it is "abused".

Here's a – somewhat contrived – example of a very bad data structure. Assume you have 16 threads parsing some text from a file. Each thread has an `id` from 0 to 15.

```
// shared state
char c[16];
FILE *file[16];

void threadFunc(int id)
{
    while ((c[id] = getc(file[id])) != EOF)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

This is safe because each thread operates on a different memory location. However, these memory locations would typically reside on the same cache line, or at most are split over two cache lines. The cache coherency protocol is then used to properly synchronize the accesses to `c[id]`. And herein lies the problem, because this forces every *other* thread to wait until the cache line becomes exclusively available before doing anything with `c[id]`, unless it is already running on the core that "owns" the cache line. Assuming several, e.g. 16, cores, cache coherency will typically transfer the cache line from one core to another all the time. For obvious reasons, this effect is known as "cache line ping-pong". It creates a horrible performance bottleneck. It is the result of a very bad case of *false sharing*, i.e. threads sharing a physical cache line without actually accessing the same logical memory locations.

In contrast to this, especially if one took the extra step of ensuring that the `file` array resides on its own cache line, using it would be completely harmless (on x86_64) from a performance perspective because the pointers are only read from, most the time. In this case, multiple cores can "share" the cache line as read-only. Only when any core tries to write to the cache line, it has to tell the other cores that it is going to "seize" the cache line for exclusive access.

(This is greatly simplified, as there are different levels of CPU caches, and several cores might share the same L2 or L3 cache, but it should give you a basic idea of the problem.)

Comment: Yes, I think that you have correctly understood my question, its underlying motive, and how it subtly differs from the earlier question linked. Among other good points, you have given a concise, interesting example of cache abuse (or could one call it, "cache thrashing"?).

Comment: @thb: We already have the term "cache-line ping-pong" to describe the performance problem with false sharing.  "Thrashing" is what happens when your working set doesn't fit in the cache.  (This is like what happens when your working set doesn't fit in RAM, and paging to swap space is happening constantly.  This is the more typical use of the term "thrashing".)

Comment: All current x86-64 CPUs *can* write a single byte to a cache line without doing a RMW cycle (not even an internally-hidden atomic RMW cycle; that would have visible performance consequences).  AFAIK they can also do single-byte stores to uncacheable memory regions.  (See Margaret's answer for how this can work for DDR3.  For actual MMIO, it turns into a PCIe message, not a memory-controller operation at all.)  Everything else you say in your answer is correct, and is related to but doesn't directly answer the question :/

Comment: @PeterCordes: This sounds like an x86-64 CPU might indeed write bytes (rsp. aligned 16-bit or 32-bit words) atomically to main memory when no or write-through caching is enabled on the page. Intel and AMD do not support partial write back of a cache line, though, or do they? I have to admit all this makes Stroustrup's remarks highly misleading for this architecture. Thanks a lot for the information!

Comment: Yes, [uncached byte / (16-bit) word / dword / qword (aligned) loads/stores are atomic.  Since Pentium, so are unaligned 16-bit loads/stores that "fit within a 32-bit bus", and that's still for *all* stores, not just cached stores, so it includes MMIO.  On Intel and AMD, the common subset of guarantees is AMD's: cached loads/stores are also guaranteed atomic if they don't cross a 64-bit boundary.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36685056/224132)  Dirty/clean is tracked per cache line, so partial write-back of a cache line isn't a thing.  It's not a coincidence that DDR burst size is 64B.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what Stroustrup meant by "WORD".
Maybe it is the minimum size of memory storage of the machine?

Anyway not all machines were created with 8bit (BYTE) resolution.
In fact I recommend this awesome article by Eric S. Raymond describing some of the history of computers:
http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/things-every-hacker-once-knew/

> "... It used also to be generally known that 36-bit architectures
>   explained some unfortunate features of the C language. The original
>   Unix machine, the PDP-7, featured 18-bit words corresponding to
>   half-words on larger 36-bit computers. These were more naturally
>   represented as six octal (3-bit) digits."

Comment: I don't think that's a sensible interpretation.  The first edition was published in 1985, and even back then "modern" would imply 8-bit bytes.  And "word" definitely doesn't mean "byte";  word-addressable machines were called word-addressable, not described as having 36-bit bytes or whatever.  Maybe he meant to write something like this, but what he did write is just plain wrong.

Comment: You may be right. I am not sure what he meant.
Anyway I think my answer adds light on the subject of machines mem resolution so keeping it with a slight edit.

Comment: in the octal days a 9 bit byte made a lot of sense and there were 9 bit byte systems with 9, 18 and 36 bit sized data items.  because it made perfect sense...  a word doesnt have to be two bytes either, look at arm and I assume mips...four bytes to a word.

Comment: In 1985, the definition of a *word* was much clearer than it is now.  It was the maximum size unit of memory which could be retrieved or written in a minimal memory transaction cycle and corresponded with the size of (most) CPU registers.  So the 8086/80186/80286 had a word size of 16 bits; the 8088 was a peculiar in emulating 16 bit words.  The 80386/80486/80586 used a 32 bit word.  Its bus structure had 4 wires which indicated which of the four bytes on the data bus being transacted were valid so single byte i/o was directly supported.

Comment: The only "modern" CPUs I can think of from that era which could not do direct byte i/o were the 1970s CDC mainframes and the DEC Alpha.  I am at a loss as to what Bjarne was thinking about when he made that statement.

Comment: @wallyk: IDK what edition of the book introduced that paragraph.  It's possible it was soon after Alpha was introduced (before it got byte load/store), and for some reason Stroustrup was super-excited about Alpha. Or he was repeating something he'd read; some high-level language designers are notorious for not being hardware experts, or at least making occasional mis-statements about hardware. (e.g. Andrei Alexandrescu (of C++ STL fame) sometimes gets things wrong about what hardware is like in his lectures, although they're otherwise very good including the performance / optimization advice.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm assuming it was introduced in the 4th edition, as C++ didn't have a concurrency model until C+11.

Comment: @RossRidge: I hope not.  As [KerrekSB points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19903338/c-memory-model-and-race-conditions-on-char-arrays/19903377#19903377) on the earlier Q about the same paragraph, it's not a C++11 data race to do concurrent writes to adjacent elements of a `char array[]`, so `char` can't be a single byte on machines without byte stores.  Plus, the quote says "*without* a well-defined and reasonable memory model".  If that was new in the 4th ed, it's a really dumb error.  Hopefully it was much earlier, when Alpha was the next big thing.

Comment: @PeterCordes Well, nonetheless it is in the 4th edition, published in 2013. The next paragraph addresses your concerns by stating "The C++ memory model guarantees that two threads of execution can update and access separate memory locations without interfering with each other. This is exactly what we would naively expect. It is the compiler’s job to protect us from the sometimes very strange and subtle behaviors of modern hardware. How a compiler and hardware combination achieves that is up to the compiler. ..."

Comment: started trying to read that link but RS232 is not a protocol it is an electrical/pinout standard, that is something that everyone should have know both now and then, you cant compare it to USB which is a pin/electrical AND protocol standard. So I had to stop reading there.

Comment: @RossRidge: Good points. I wasn't trying to get at what the C++ standard formally guarantees. As Arne illustrates, C++ can best help the programmer to improve performance if the programmer grasps *why* the C++ standard guarantees what it does.

Answer (score 1):

Stroustrup is *not* saying that no machine can perform loads and stores smaller than their native word size, he is saying that a machine *couldn't*.

While this seems surprising at first, it's nothing esoteric.
For starter, we will ignore the cache hierarchy, we will take that into account later.
Assume there are no caches between the CPU and the memory.

The big problem with memory is *density*, trying to put more bits possible into the smallest area.
In order to achieve that it is convenient, from an electrical design point of view, to expose a bus as wider as possible (this favours the reuse of some electrical signals, I haven't looked at the specific details though).
So, in architecture where big memories are needed (like the x86) or a simple low-cost design is favourable (for example where RISC machines are involved), the memory bus is larger than the smallest addressable unit (typically the byte).

Depending on the budget and legacy of the project the memory can expose a wider bus alone or along with some sideband signals to select a particular unit into it.
What does this mean practically?
If you take a look at the [datasheet of a DDR3 DIMM](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Micron%20Technology%20Inc%20PDFs/MT16JTFxxx64AY.pdf) you'll see that there are 64 *DQ0–DQ63* pins to read/write the data.
This is the data bus, 64-bit wide, 8 bytes at a time.
This 8 bytes thing is very well founded in the x86 architecture to the point that Intel refers to it in the WC section of its optimisation manual where it says that data are transferred from the 64 *bytes* fill buffer (remember: we are ignoring the caches for now, but this is similar to how a cache line gets written back) in bursts of 8 bytes (hopefully, continuously).

Does this mean that the x86 can only write QWORDS (64-bit)?
No, the same datasheet shows that each DIMM has the *DM0–DM7 ,DQ0–DQ7* and *DQS0–DQS7* signals to mask, direct and strobe each of the 8 bytes in the 64-bit data bus.

So x86 can read and write bytes natively and atomically.
However, now it's easy to see that this could not be the case for every architecture.
For instance, the VGA video memory was DWORD (32-bit) addressable and making it fit in the byte addressable world of the 8086 led to the messy bit-planes.

In general specific purpose architecture, like DSPs, could not have a byte addressable memory at the hardware level.

There is a twist: we have just talked about the memory data bus, this is the lowest layer possible.
Some CPUs can have instructions that build a byte addressable memory on top of a word addressable memory.
What does that mean?
It's easy to load a smaller part of a word: just discard the rest of the bytes!
Unfortunately, I can't recall the name of the architecture (if it even existed at all!) where the processor simulated a load of an unaligned byte by reading the aligned word containing it and rotating the result before saving it in a register.

With stores, the matter is more complex: if we can't simply write the part of the word that we just updated we need to write the unchanged remaining part too.
The CPU, or the programmer, must read the old content, update it and write it back.
This is a Read-Modify-Write operation and it is a core concept when discussing atomicity.

Consider:

```
/* Assume unsigned char is 1 byte and a word is 4 bytes */
unsigned char foo[4] = {};

/* Thread 0                         Thread 1                 */
foo[0] = 1;                        foo[1] = 2;
```

Is there a data race?
This is safe on x86 because they can write bytes, but what if the architecture cannot?
Both threads would have to read the *whole* `foo` array, modify it and write it back.
In *pseudo-C* this would be

```
/* Assume unsigned char is 1 byte and a word is 4 bytes */
unsigned char foo[4] = {};

/* Thread 0                        Thread 1                 */

/* What a CPU would do (IS)        What a CPU would do (IS) */
int tmp0 = *((int*)foo)            int tmp1 = *((int*)foo)

/* Assume little endian            Assume little endian     */
tmp0 = (tmp0 & ~0xff) | 1;         tmp1 = (tmp1 & ~0xff00) | 0x200;

/* Store it back                   Store it back            */
*((int*)foo) = tmp0;               *((int*)foo) = tmp1;
```

We can now see what Stroustrup was talking about: the two stores `*((int*)foo) = tmpX` obstruct each other, to see this consider this possible execution sequence:

```
int tmp0 = *((int*)foo)                   /* T0  */ 
tmp0 = (tmp0 & ~0xff) | 1;                /* T1  */        
int tmp1 = *((int*)foo)                   /* T1  */
tmp1 = (tmp1 & ~0xff00) | 0x200;          /* T1  */
*((int*)foo) = tmp1;                      /* T0  */
*((int*)foo) = tmp0;                      /* T0, Whooopsy  */
```

If the C++ didn't have a *memory model* these kinds of nuisances would have been implementation specific details, leaving the C++ a useless programming language in a multithreading environment.

Considering how common is the situation depicted in the toy example, Stroustrup *stressed out* the importance of a well-defined memory model.
Formalizing a memory model is hard work, it's an exhausting, error-prone and abstract process so I also see a bit of *pride* in the words of Stroustrup.

I have not brushed up on the C++ memory model but updating different array elements [is fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30758663/c-c-arrays-with-threads-do-i-need-to-use-mutexes-or-locks).
That's a very strong guarantee.

We have left out the caches but that doesn't really change anything, at least for the x86 case.
The x86 writes to memory through the caches, the caches are evicted in lines of 64 *bytes*.
Internally each core can update a line at any position atomically unless a load/store crosses a line boundary (e.g. by writing near the end of it).
This can be avoided by naturally aligning data (can you prove that?).

In a multi-code/socket environment, the cache coherency protocol ensures that only a CPU at a time is allowed to freely write to a cached line of memory (the CPU that has it in the Exclusive or Modified state).
Basically, the MESI family of protocol use a concept similar to locking found the DBMSs.
This has the effect, for the writing purpose, of "assigning" different memory regions to different CPUs.
So it doesn't really affect the discussion of above.

Comment: The problem is that Bjarne said that the inability to write anything smaller than a word applies to _most modern hardware_, but it doesn't seem like there has been any point in time where that was close to being true.

Comment: @BeeOnRope, very true. It's possible he has been exposed to an entirely different category of hardware but it's unlikely. Most likely, he was trying to make a point :)