# Why a 32-bit SoC has registers with size of 1 or 2 bytes?

Tags: cpu-architecture, cpu-registers

I'm reading the data sheet of a network processor SoC. It has a MIPS32 CPU core and many integrated function blocks. When I came across the registers map of one of these blocks, I see that there are many registers whose size is 1 or 2 bytes:

[image: register_map]

I have always thought that in 32-bit architecture, the register size is always 4 bytes, and the address offsets of registers are always a multiple of 4.

Am I misunderstanding a fundamental concept of computer architecture here?

Comment: x86_64 has many 16-bit segment registers beside 8, 16 and 32-bit normal registers, and the flag register doesn't contain even all 32 bits. It also have 64/128/256/512-bit SIMD registers[

Answer (score 2):

Those are [memory-mapped I/O registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_I/O) for peripherals built-in to the SoC (the ethernet HW in this case), **not "CPU registers"**.

MIPS has byte load/store instructions, so there's no obstacle to writing a device driver using MMIO on those byte registers.  [MIPS's `lb` instruction](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html) does a zero-extending byte load into a 32-bit CPU register.  Whether you're processing a string one char at a time or writing a device driver that talks to hardware with memory-mapped byte registers, it's all the same.

There is a specific benefit to using byte registers, other than just using less address-space for registers that don't need to be larger: **A word load/store can atomically access multiple byte MMIO registers**, at least with respect to CPU interrupts.  (i.e. the CPU doesn't have to disable interrupts in a pre-emptible kernel device driver to atomically modify multiple related registers).

---

Related: [all modern architectures can natively do byte loads/stores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46721075/can-modern-x86-hardware-not-store-a-single-byte-to-memory/46818162#46818162).  Early Alpha AXP was the only recent exception, and it has a special sparse I/O region where word loads/stores mapped to byte loads/stores so it could still use normal hardware that had some byte registers, instead of only being able to use ethernet cards designed to be programmed with only word I/O.

Comment: Sub-word I/O registers also allow multiple (presumably related) registers to be set atomically with respect to interrupts (without having to disable interrupts).

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton: An interesting, thanks!  I don't write device drivers, I didn't know if it generally worked properly or not to do wider loads/stores that overlapped multiple MMIO registers.  Cool to hear that it does work.