# How many and what size cycles will be needed to perform longword transferred to the CPU

Tags: cpu, cpu-architecture, processor, cpu-cycles, coldfire

The task is for architecture ColdFire processor MCF5271:

[image: question]

I don't understand how many and what size cycles will be needed to perform a longword transfer to the CPU, or word transfers. I'm reading the chart and I don't see what the connection is? Any comments are very appreciated. I've attached 2 examples with the answers.

[DATA BUS SIZE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUmjK.png)

Comment: So the CPU is 68000? Because 68000 has a 16-bit data bus only, but it seems from the image that the data bus is 32-bit wide.

Comment: x86 my mistake @HadiBrais

Comment: Which x86 processor? We have to understand first what the address and data buses look like.

Comment: MCF5271 @HadiBrais

Comment: [MCF5271](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NXP_ColdFire) is not an x86 processor, it's a ColdFire processor.

Comment: ColdFire processor MCF5271 is the one im asking about then @HadiBrais

Comment: Your last image link is a m68k register diagram, not busses.

Comment: now its busses @PeterCordes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MCF5271 manual](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/reference-manual/MCF5271RM.pdf) discusses the external interface of the processor in Chapter 17. The processor implements a byte-addressable address space with a 32-bit external data bus. The D[31:0] signals represent the data bus, the A[23:0] signals represent the address bus, and the BS[3:0] (active low) signals represent the byte enable signals. Even though the the data bus 32-bit wide, the memory module connected to it can be 32-bit, 16-bit, or 8-bit wide. This is referred to as the memory port size. Figure 17-2 from that chapter shows how all of these signals are related to each other.

[image]

Table 17-2 from the same chapter shows the supported transfer sizes (Specified by a signal called TSIZ[1:0]).

[image]

The A[0] and A[1](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/reference-manual/MCF5271RM.pdf) address signals specify the alignment of the transfer. Memory alignment is defined in Section 17.7 of the same chapter.

> Because  operands  can  reside  at  any  byte  boundary,  unlike 
>   opcodes,  they  are  allowed  to  be misaligned. A byte operand is
>   properly aligned at any address, a word operand is misaligned at an
>   odd  address,  and  a  longword  is  misaligned  at  an   address  not
>   a  multiple   of  four.  Although  the MCF5271 enforces no alignment
>   restrictions  for data operands (including program counter (PC)
>   relative data addressing), additional bus cycles are required for
>   misaligned operands.

Putting all of that information together, we can easily determine how many cycles are required to transfer a 1-byte, 2-byte, 4-byte datum to any memory location (aligned or misaligned) through a memory port of size 1-byte, 2-byte, or 4-byte.

Let's consider the example from the image you've attached. How to store a longword at address 0x0000003 through a 32-bit memory port? Focus on the rows where the port size is 32-bit. We have A[1:0] = 11. So first a single-byte transfer must be performed with BS[3:0] = 1110. The other three bytes need to be transferred to locations 0x0000004 (A[1:0] = 00), 0x0000005 (A[1:0] = 01), and 0x0000006 (A[1:0] = 10). This can be done using either three single-byte transfers (which would take three cycles) or using a single two-byte transfer followed by a single one-byte transfer (which would take two cycles).