# How 64bit cpu fetch 8bits(generally 1 Byte) of data from ram

Tags: 64-bit, cpu-architecture

While learning about computer architecture, I came to know about CPUs fetch-execute cycle, ISA, buses and other stuffs. Each CPU can perform on different bit sized data based on their architecture (like 8, 16, 32, 64 bits). Consider 64bit CPU, it can perform on 64bit sized data at a time. To support this all three address, data and control buses can transmit 64bit data at a time. We use the term called "WORD" to mention how many bits can processed by CPU at a time (for 64bit CPU the "WORD" size will be 64bit). Each instructions used in the 64bit CPU will also in 64bit size.

Programmers generally uses the "Byte" as a unit for memory and we develop programs in the intention of using Byte as a unit (like char, int, long, float from C language for example).

My Doubts:
Consider 64bit CPU.

1. Whether if CPU uses Word size or byte size for addressing the RAM.
   for ex:
   for simplicity, we take RAM size as 256 bits. If the CPU give address for each 64bit(WORD). Then       there will be total of 4 addresses. else the CPU give address for each 8bit(Byte). then there will be total of 32 address.
2. If programmer uses Byte size, then how will be it fetch from word.
   for ex: consider char data type in C language and it takes 1Byte(8bit).
   Whether CPU fetch complete 64bit from RAM or it fetch only 8bit to process char type.
3. During Fetch-Execute cycle 64bit CPU will fetch 64bit sized instruction. Each 64bit instruction will be use full size or split into parts based on operation we perform. Some operation require no operands, some require 1 or more operands. for example add will 2 operands, the ISA will be three parts each for opcode, operand1, operand2. Imagine, In 64bit, first 16bits will be opcode, 24bit for operand1 and 24bit for operand2.  If we use address for indicate to take data from that address as operand and that address needs to use complete 64bit size to store that address. Then how will be that address will be used in 64bit ISA if only 24bits will used for operands. Whether it take multiple ISA to perform that operation or anything else?

Comment: Processors don't read from RAM, they read from cache.  L1 is byte-addressable.  https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/42214/loading-a-word-from-a-byte-addressed-cache

Comment: *During Fetch-Execute cycle 64bit CPU will fetch 64bit sized instruction.* - That would be unusual.  Only a few VLIW ISAs have fixed-width 64-bit instructions.  More common is 32-bit instructions, like most 64-bit RISCs such as Alpha, RISC-V 64-bit, MIPS III, PowerPC64, etc.  Also, 64-bit ISAs are pretty universally register machines, so each operand field is only like 5 bits to select one of 32 registers.  See https://www.codementor.io/@erikeidt/classifications-of-instruction-set-architectures-zekccx74c for example.

Comment: Near duplicate of [How does a 64-bit computer change one byte in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66050103) except that's about real x86-64 CPUs, not your hypothetical weird machine which might not even have cache.  See [How many and what size cycles will be needed to perform longword transferred to the CPU](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49882244) for some details about the bus in ColdFire CPUs, how they can signal single-byte accesses to DRAM instead of just reading whole cache lines.

Comment: related: [Are there any modern CPUs where a cached byte store is actually slower than a word store?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54217528) re: modifying a byte in cache.  Re: memory and cache in general, see **[How much of ‘What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory’ is still valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47714514)** - all of the basics, go read that to understand how real CPUs with cache access memory.

Comment: Also note that modern ISAs pretty universally use byte-addressable memory, so every byte has its own address.  Without that, you couldn't do a byte load or store in the first place, at least not as a single instruction.  You could load a word and shift / AND to extract the 8 bits you want, like on word-addressable DSPs.  ([Can modern x86 hardware not store a single byte to memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/80393266))