# What does the C++ compiler do to ensure that different but adjacent memory locations are safe to be used on different threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

Lets say I have a struct:

```
struct Foo {
  char a;  // read and written to by thread 1 only
  char b;  // read and written to by thread 2 only
};
```

Now from what I understand, the C++ standard guarantees the safety of the above when two threads operate on the two different memory locations.

I would think though that, since char a and char b, fall within the same cache line, that the compiler has to do extra syncing.

What exactly happens here?

Comment: On a lot of platforms (for example, x86), it doesn't have to do anything. It just works (it means that the HW does the necessary extra stuff).

Comment: Would that imply additional latency then incurred even if by the x86 hardware?

Comment: Yes. But the exact hit could vary on different generations/vendors of CPU. Do a search on "false sharing".

Comment: This is handled by the hardware, not the compiler, as far as I am aware. This is called false sharing

Comment: I think the only CPUs that C++ has actually been implemented on that the compiler would have to do anything special to support the C++ memory model are early Alpha CPUs which lacked instructions that could atomically set a single byte (or 16-bit) memory location. See Peter Cordes answer to a related question for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46818162/3826372  As far as know there's no compiler implementations that have been updated to support the C++11 memory model on these long obsolete Alpha CPUs.

Comment: @RossRidge - well, there's the even more obsolete TMS9900 that has the same issue (only with 8-bit values, as it assumes 16-bit alignment) -- there's a port of gcc 3.4 to the architecture, but I don't know whether any particular C++ variant is supported.  I'm also not aware of any extant dual-processor TMS9900 machines that would ever actually see this issue.  The TMS9900 has instructions that operate on single bytes, but the bus implementation always fetches both bytes in a 16-bit word and rewrites the unchanged one.

Comment: @Jules: But does that read + rewrite happen atomically, or could another core actually have a store stepped-on by that effect?  If it's atomic, then it's no different from [Are there any modern/ancient CPUs / microcontrollers where a cached byte store is actually slower than a word store?](//stackoverflow.com/q/54217528) : yes apparently many non-x86 CPUs do a RMW when committing narrow stores to L1d cache, to update ECC data with 4 or 8-byte granularity.  (But store coalescing in the store buffer often helps avoid needing to do that.)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is hardware-dependent. On hardware I am familiar with, C++ doesn't have to do anything special, because from hardware perspective accessing different bytes even on a cached line is handled 'transparently'. From the hardware, this situation is not really different from

```
char a[2];
// or
char a, b;
```

In the cases above, we are talking about two adjacent objects, which are guaranteed to be independently accessible.

However, I've put 'transparently' in quotes for a reason. When you really have a case like that, you could be suffering (performance-wise) from a 'false sharing' - which happens when two (or more) threads access adjacent memory simultaneously and it ends up being cached in several CPU's caches. This leads to constant cache invalidation. In the real life, care should be taken to prevent this from happening when possible.

Comment: `care should be taken to prevent this from happening when possible.` How would you suggest one going about doing that?

Comment: @ArtB there is no hard and fast rule. Designing program correctly from the scratch is always the best approach. You can also try profiling tools, such as valgrind and analyze the number of cache misses.

Comment: @ArtB - can be done by adding padding members to structs to separate fields into different cache lines.  There are plenty of papers/blog posts/etc out there discussing how to measure to see if you've got a problem and then how to ameliorate it.

Comment: @ArtB: C++17 provides [interference sizes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/hardware_destructive_interference_size) to help guide such design.

Answer (score 23):

As others have explained, nothing in particular on common hardware. However, there is a catch: The compiler must refrain from performing certain optimizations, unless it can prove that other threads don't access the memory locations in question, e.g.:

```
std::array<std::uint8_t, 8u> c;

void f()
{
    c[0] ^= 0xfa;
    c[3] ^= 0x10;
    c[6] ^= 0x8b;
    c[7] ^= 0x92;
}
```

Here, in a single-threaded memory model, the compiler could emit code like the following (pseudo-assembly; assumes little-endian hardware):

```
load r0, *(std::uint64_t *) &c[0]
xor r0, 0x928b0000100000fa
store r0, *(std::uint64_t *) &c[0]
```

This is likely to be faster on common hardware than xor'ing the individual bytes. However, it reads and writes the unaffected (and unmentioned) elements of `c` at indices 1, 2, 4 and 5. If other threads are writing to these memory locations concurrently, these changes could be overwritten.

For this reason, optimizations like these are often unusable in a multi-threaded memory model. As long as the compiler performs only loads and stores of matching length, or merges accesses only when there is no gap (e.g. the accesses to `c[6]` and `c[7]` can still be merged), the hardware commonly already provides the necessary guarantees for correct execution.

(That said, there are/have been some architectures with weak and counterintuitive memory order guarantees, e.g. DEC Alpha does not track pointers as a data dependency in the way that other architectures do, so it is necessary to introduce an explicit memory barrier in some cases, in low level code. There is a somewhat well-known [little rant by Linus Torvalds on this issue](https://lkml.org/lkml/2012/2/1/521). However, a conforming C++ implementation *is* expected to shield you from such issues.)

Comment: It's not the optimization that are unsafe in a multithread model, but the code itself. Unless the whole thing is protected by a mutex, code that reads and writes those locations from different threads is already invalid and whatever happens happens. This means that the compiler is indeed free to optimize this code with a single read-write operation because no **valid** code would be able to tell the difference.

Comment: @6502 As I said, I'm assuming another thread could access *other* elements of `c`, i.e. `c[i]` where `i` is one of 1, 2, 4, 5. You seem to claim that any access to `c` from another thread is a data race, but that is not so. To quote [(intro.memory/3)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.memory#3): "A memory location is either an object of scalar type or a maximal sequence of adjacent bit-fields all having nonzero width." – i.e. `c` is not a memory location because it's neither a scalar nor an element of a bit field.

Comment: An element of an array of scalar types is an object of scalar type. A thread reading items 0 and 1 has no problem of concurrency with a thread writing element 2, even if it uses a single machine instruction. A thread reading elements 0 and 1 has a problem with a thread writing element 1 even using separate instructions if there is no mutex. Of course code reading items 0 and 1 cannot use a single instruction that reads e.g. 4 items and then drop the extra data because this could indeed introduce bad reads because of another thread writing in the part that is going to be discarded.