# Can std::replace implementation make redundant writes to the passed array?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, vectorization, sse, avx

`std::replace` implementation can be optimized using vectorization (by specializing the library implementation or by the compiler).

The vectorized implementation would compare and replace several elements at once.

To make sure old values preserved where needed, the vectorized implementation has to do either of following:

1. Use masked vector stores
2. Write old values for non-replaced elements
3. Vectorize only locating of the elements, still replace each by individual store

The first approach looks the best, but does not work if the vector instruction set is lacking masked store with given element size. On x86, the SSE family does not have masked stores<sup>1</sup>, AVX/AVX2 has only 32 and 64 bit element masked stores, and only if some AVX512 subsets are available, every vector element size masked store is available.

The second approach assumes that the element can be written, if the same value is written. Which is the assumption I question. The writability of memory is not always granted. In C++, one can pass constant array with casted away `const` modifier to `std::replace`, and expect the correct no-operation if nothing is to replaced. With OS memory management function, the array can be made partially-writable, partially-read-only.

The third approach doesn't need masked store, doesn't make writability assumption. But it also doesn't fully benefit from vectorization.

I observed different approaches being used by different implementations. Both `x86-64 icc 2021.10.0` compiler and `x86-64 clang 17.0.1` attempt to vectorize `std::replace` with 16-bit elements with AVX2 enabled, but Intel uses write old values approach, whereas clang uses individual stores approach. Used the following code and `-mavx2` option.

```
#include <algorithm>

void f(short* i, short* e)
{
    std::replace(i, e, 0, 1);
}
```

See https://godbolt.org/z/oarPhPhTs.

So it looks like as either `x86-64 icc 2021.10.0` is broken or `x86-64 clang 17.0.1` is missing further optimization opportunity.

Besides vectorization itself, redundant writes may be used to optimize `std::replace` for small arrays or for vectorization tail handling: branchless code may want to compute the destination value (e.g. using `cmovcc` on x86) and store it unconditionally,

So my question is - are compilers and standard library implementations allowed to make redundant stores to optimize `std::replace`?

---

This question is different from near-duplicate [Crash with icc: can the compiler invent writes where none existed in the abstract machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54524947/2945027) in that it is about the standard algorithm `std::replace`, not a particular its implementation or hand-written equivalent.

---

<sup>1</sup> Non-temporal masked stores don't count, as they are not useful for general-purpose optimizations

Comment: Related: [Crash with icc: can the compiler invent writes where none existed in the abstract machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54524947). Though [`std::replace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace) seems to require that `*first` is writable.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is a duplicate, or if, e.g. `for(...) *first = *first == old_value ? new_value : *first;` would be a legal implementation of `std::replace`

Comment: @chtz I actually now realize my mistake. Agree it is not a duplicate

Comment: There is actually a `replace_copy`, which always overwrites. Especially for POD types this is probably always preferable (unless you use ICC): https://godbolt.org/z/7oqWbd9fa (I hardcoded the array-length to remove some of the noise).

Comment: @chtz, I realize there's `replace_copy`, but I want plain `replace` to vectorize too in STL implementations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is that **redundant writes are not allowed**.

[[algorithms.requirements]/3](https://eel.is/c++draft/algorithms#requirements-3) says:

> For purposes of determining the existence of data races, algorithms shall not modify objects referenced through an iterator argument unless the specification requires such modification.

I can imagine a case where a redundant write by `std::replace` modification introduces data races.

Consider some array with some of elements of `x` values, and some other values. Let's assume it is divided into subranges by `x` values, and the `x` values themselves are not included into that subranges. Now if we run a non-modifying algorithm on each subrange in one thread, and `std::replace` in another thread, to replace `x` with `y`, we should not have a data race. With redundant writes we will have.