# movb causes bad speculation

Tags: c++, assembly, x86-64, clang++, mov

I am working on a parallel tree implementation. During profiling, I have recognized high bad speculation on `movb` operation.

My data structure looks as follows:

```
struct data {
    enum annotation_type : std::uint8_t { none, core, region, tree_node }; // Specifies the value in the union
    access_pattern _access_pattern = writing;
    enum priority _priority = priority::normal;

    annotation_type _annotation_type = annotation_type::none;
    union {
        std::uint16_t _core;
        std::uint8_t _region;
        std::pair<node*, std::uint16_t> _tree_node = {nullptr,0};
    };
};
```

During traversal of the tree, I will update the `_annotation_type` and the value of the `union` regularly using the following function:

```
void annotate(const node* node, const std::uint16_t size) noexcept
{
    _annotation_type = annotation_type::tree_node;
    _tree_node = {node, size};
}
```

By `clang-10`, the `annotate` method is compiled to

```
movb  $0x3, 0x12(%r14)   // Set _annotation_type
movq  %rax, 0x14(%r14)   // Set the pointer part of tree_node
movw  $0x200, 0x1c(%r14) // Set the size part of tree_node, in this case it is called with annotate(node*, 512)
```

Using Intel VTune Profiler, I can detemine a CPI Rate of `4.550` and a bad speculation of `53.0%` for the `movb` instruction `movb  $0x3, 0x12(%r14)` which updates the `_annotation_type` attribute to `0x3` (`tree_node`).

But how can a `mov` instruction get such a high bad speculation, which is based on branch misspredition, isn't it?

Comment: Are you reading from an inactive union member at any time?

Comment: What is an inactive union? The only knowledge of what value is stored in the union is the `_annotation_type`.

Comment: If you store something in `_tree_node` the [inactive union members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373203/accessing-inactive-union-member-and-undefined-behavior) are `_core` and `_region`.

Comment: Btw, the `pair` stores a `node*` but the `annotate` (member?) function tries to store a `const node*`. Does that even compile?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Ah, no, I do not access one of the inactive union members.

Comment: I vaguely remember that there is penalty when doing byte operations in some circumstances, but its more a read-write queue problem.

Comment: I note that the `std::pair<node*, std::uint16_t> _tree_node` appears to be 4 byte (not 8 byte) aligned ?

Comment: Why would you write this yourself, rather than use `std::variant`?

Comment: @Surt: x86 byte and 16-bit operations sometimes can cause partial register penalties, but no partial registers are involved in that instruction, only an immediate and memory.  Unlike some non-x86 microarchitectures, [x86 byte stores are just as efficient as dword stores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46721075/can-modern-x86-hardware-not-store-a-single-byte-to-memory).  I'd guess the mis-speculation might be in whatever conditionally calls this function, not due to anything the store itself is doing.  Loads can cause memory-order mis-speculation machine clears, but not stores.