# Can multiple threads do "atomic" lockfree writes to different bytes in an array?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, parallel-processing, pthreads

Can `N` threads do "atomic" lockfree writes of length `k` non-overlapping intervals of `x`-bit elements in an array of `M` `x`-bit elements (for `N` at most `M`)?

Eg. suppose `N` is `10`, `M` is `10`, `k` is 1 and `x` is `8`.

Then we have `10` threads, an array of `10` bytes, and each threads writes `1` byte to the array. (Each thread writes to a **different** byte, because the intervals are non-overlapping, by hypothesis.)

---

Here's a program that tests whether this is possible, or if a thread "steps on his neighbor's toes".

```
/*
t gcc-8  bytes1.c -o bytes1  -lpthread  &&  t ./bytes1
*/
#include <stdint.h>
typedef  uint8_t   u8;
typedef  int32_t  i32;
typedef  int64_t  i64;

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
/* @blk1  test if multiple threads can do 1-byte aligned lockfree atomic writes to an array! */
#define THRS_TEST_LOCKFREE_WRITES_DX    0x20
#define THRS_TEST_LOCKFREE_WRITES_TMUL  2  // thread multiplier (for the numbre of threads)!

typedef struct{
  i32       idx;
  i32       tdim;
  pthread_t pthr;

  i32       dx;
  u8*       g_data;
}thr_t;

void* thr_test_lockfree_write(void* arg){
  thr_t* thr = (thr_t*)arg;
  for(int i=0; i<thr->dx; ++i)
    thr->g_data[thr->idx*thr->dx + i] = thr->idx;
  return NULL;
}

void thrs_test_lockfree_writes(){
  i32    thrs_idim = THRS_TEST_LOCKFREE_WRITES_TMUL * sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN);
  thr_t* thrs      = alloca(sizeof(thr_t)*thrs_idim);
  i32    x_dx      = THRS_TEST_LOCKFREE_WRITES_DX;
  i64    x_idim    = x_dx*thrs_idim;
  u8*    x_data    = aligned_alloc(0x1000, sizeof(u8)*x_idim);

  for(int i=0; i<thrs_idim; ++i){
    thrs[i].idx    = i;
    thrs[i].tdim   = thrs_idim;
    thrs[i].dx     = x_dx;
    thrs[i].g_data = x_data;
    pthread_create(&thrs[i].pthr, NULL, thr_test_lockfree_write, &thrs[i]);
  }

  for(int i=0; i<thrs_idim; ++i){
    pthread_join(thrs[i].pthr, NULL);
  }

  putchar(0x0a);
  for(int i=0; i<x_idim/x_dx; ++i){
    printf("\x1b[32m%02x\x1b[91m/\x1b[37m%02x  \x1b[0m", i,thrs_idim-1);
    i32 flag = 1;
    for(int j=0; j<x_dx; ++j){
      printf("%02x", x_data[i*x_dx+j]);
      flag &= x_data[i*x_dx+j]==i%0x100;
    }
    printf(" %d\n",flag);
  }

  free(x_data);
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
int main(){
  thrs_test_lockfree_writes();
  puts("\nbye!");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

> Can N threads do "atomic" lockfree writes

On architectures where writing a single byte to memory is possible (which is all modern architectures), yes.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46818162/50617), and note that the level of parallelism your program will actually achieve will be far lower than one might expect due to [false sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing).

Comment: That's interesting. According to this [article](https://parallelcomputing2017.wordpress.com/2017/03/17/understanding-false-sharing/), multithreaded code **with** false sharing can sometimes be **slower** than serial code **without** false sharing (although I expect that to be true mostly for rare, degenerate cases, like updating the same byte over and over).

Comment: @étale-cohomology, many performance penalties specific to parallel code can in some cases be so impactful that serial code for the same task compares favorably.