# Can every MOV instruction be replaced with a PUSH/POP?

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86-64

Just curious if all `MOV`'s could be replaced with `PUSH/POP`'s in a program?

I understand such replacements are not practical and inefficient.

This [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/5eTszsxYx) example shows a standard printf call using MOV and another printf with PUSH/POP for comparison. My intuition says it's possible but there are probably some gotchas along the way?

```
#include <stdio.h>

char format_string[] asm("format_string") = "%d %d %d %d %d\n";

void MOV_printf() {
    __asm__ (
        "subq $128, %%rsp\n\t"
        "lea format_string(%%rip), %%rdi\n\t"
        "movq $1, %%rsi\n\t"
        "movq $2, %%rdx\n\t"
        "movq $3, %%rcx\n\t"
        "movq $4, %%r8\n\t"
        "movq $5, %%r9\n\t"
        "call printf\n\t"
        "addq $136, %%rsp\n"
        ::: "rdi", "rsi", "rdx", "rcx", "r8", "r9", "rsp"
    );
}

void PUSH_POP_printf() {
    __asm__ (
        "subq $128, %%rsp\n\t"
        "lea format_string(%%rip), %%rdi\n\t"
        "pushq $1\n\t" 
        "popq %%rsi\n\t"
        "pushq $2\n\t" 
        "popq %%rdx\n\t"
        "pushq $3\n\t" 
        "popq %%rcx\n\t"
        "pushq $4\n\t" 
        "popq %%r8\n\t"
        "pushq $5\n\t" 
        "popq %%r9\n\t"
        "call printf\n\t"
        "addq $136, %%rsp\n"
        ::: "rdi", "rsi", "rdx", "rcx", "r8", "r9", "rsp"
    );        
}

int main() {
    MOV_printf();
    PUSH_POP_printf();
    return 0;
}
```

**Solutions**

`MOV r64, imm64` --- Replace with 4 `pushw` and a `popq`. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/bxabW1ePx)

`MOV AH,DL` --- Simulate it using `push/pop` and a scratch buffer. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/fex8GdMKW)

**Gotchas**

A `mov` is required for these

- Control Registers (CR0, CR2, CR3, CR4, etc.,...)
- Debug Registers (DR0, DR1, DR2, etc.,...)

Comment: `push` does not take a 64 bit immediate so it won't work for `mov r64, imm64`. Also there are other kinds of `mov` instructions such as moving to control or debug registers.

Comment: But other than that, it is largely correct, but a not very profound insight, if you ask me.

Comment: @Jester: It's a bit of a hack, but you can push two 32-bit immediates and pop it into a 64-bit register/memory.  It doesn't force alignment.

Comment: 32 bit immediates are sign extended to 64, but you can push 16 bits so doing 4 of those would work.

Comment: An invisible consequence of using `push` and `pop` is that you have to declare the stack pointer changes in your exception unwinding metadata.

Comment: Assuming the `push` succeeds the `pop` can't really cause a problem so you should not ever get an exception between the two which means the stack pointer gets restored so you don't have to bother with unwind info. You might get a signal though.

Comment: You can also `mov` 8 bits without changing the rest of the register. How about some `mov ah, dl`? And don't forget that 32 bit `mov` zero extends but `push` sign extends (can work around that with the `pushw`)

Comment: `mov %al,  (%rdi)` is not possible with `push`.  Any emulation that loads/stores the containing word or qword and stores it back won't be thread-safe; non-atomic RMW of the containing word could step on a store to the other byte by another thread.

Comment: Also, x86-64 removed the opcodes for push/pop of segment registers other than FS/GS.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/push.  So `mov ds, eax` is not emulatable either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Byte stores like `mov %al,  (%rdi)` are not possible with `push`**.  Any emulation that loads/stores the containing word or qword and stores it back won't be thread-safe; non-atomic RMW of the containing word could step on a store to the other byte by another thread.  (*[Can modern x86 hardware not store a single byte to memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46721075/can-modern-x86-hardware-not-store-a-single-byte-to-memory)* - it can, so can most ISAs, despite misconceptions.)

If you're willing to accept non-thread-safe emulation, then perhaps partially-overlapping `pop m16` operations could construct a word with the value you're looking for in a static buffer, which you can `pop m16` / `push m16` to copy over the original byte.

But you won't know whether the byte at `(%rdi)` is the low or high byte of the 16-bit word that contains it, so you won't know which of `-1(%rdi)` or `0(%rdi)` you can access without **possibly segfaulting by going into the next page**.  Only an *aligned* 16-bit load / store is guaranteed not to cross any wider boundaries (like 4k page), and thus can't page-fault if the word contains any bytes you know are valid.  (*[Is it safe to read past the end of a buffer within the same page on x86 and x64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800739/is-it-safe-to-read-past-the-end-of-a-buffer-within-the-same-page-on-x86-and-x64)*)

`push`/`pop` alone can't check the low bit of `%rdi` and branch accordingly.

(x86-64 makes it impossible to have segment limits, which in 32-bit mode could have been an odd number of bytes, in the general case not assuming a flat memory model.  But actually, x86-64 (still?) makes odd segment bases possible for FS and GS, I think, so `mov %al, %fs:(%rdi)` is even more unknown; even if you could `test %1, %dil` ; `jnz`, that still wouldn't tell you whether the linear address was odd or even.)

---

Also, in addition to debug and control registers, x86-64 removed the opcodes for push/pop of segment registers other than FS/GS.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/push.  So `mov ds, eax` is not emulatable either.

Comment: Interesting...so the instruction `mov %al,  (%rdi)` cannot be emulated with just `push/pop`'s but it could be achieved by other instructions such as  `andb $0x00, (%rdi)` and `orb %al, (%rdi)`. However, as you said, such instructions are non-atomic, etc.,... So, is it true to say that a program could theoretically have all `mov`'s replaced but would have to be done very carefully to avoid thread safety issues, non-atomic RMW, modifying flags register, page faults, etc.,...? Thanks.

Comment: @vengy: I guess I was thinking in ISO C++ terms, where `mov %al, (%rdi)` is already writing that one byte, so it would be data-race UB for other threads to look at it, but we can't go messing with surrounding bytes.  As long as this was just a plain `uint8_t`, the `and` / `or` emulation is valid, but not for lock-free `std::atomic<uint8_t>` or for `volatile`.  And yeah, you can't do an atomic 32-bit store either.  (Two 16-bit halves using `pop m16` aren't one atomic transaction).

Comment: @vengy: I noticed the Godbolt link in your question with a proposed emulation for `MOV AH,DL` uses AND/OR and a shift.  None of those are `push`.  If you're going to allow that, `and ah,0` / `or ah, dl` makes it trivial.  But like I already mentioned in this answer, I suspect that with some static scratch space, like `popw buf+1(%rip)` / `pushw buf(%rip)` / `pop %ax`, you could do something.  As long as you don't mind clobbering the red-zone, and can save/restore some scratch registers.

Comment: @vengy: If you're talking about modifying an existing binary to replace all `mov` instructions, it had better have been compiled with `-mno-red-zone`.  And probably needs to be single-threaded, or at least not using std::atomic, only mutexes, and you might not be able to replace a `movl $0, (%rdi)` in `pthread_mutex_unlock`, unless only the low byte of the mutex actually matters so you could use a word pop.  push/pop don't affect FLAGS so that's not a concern.  If you broaden it to other replacements, then yes that's a potential problem if an instruction after `mov` reads FLAGS.

Comment: Very nice idea about using a static scratch space and then applying `push/pop`'s to it. I'll try updating the godbolt link to implement that technique rather than using the trivial `and/or`. Thanks!